# how does the android software stack work?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, hardware

I'm a hardware noobie, a friend asked me a question and I told him I would find out for him. He is thinking about doing some work with producing Androids in a country where it's not so common place yet. He wants to use local manufacturers. He found some people who are making "android" hardware.

What exactly does that mean? Where would development have to begin? Write drivers to go into the kernel, or do manufacturers generally provide these along with the hardware? Can he just dive into creating a custom android operating system?

I work with AI and higher level stuff, this is not my cup of tea. Any information or links would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a specific enough question to really answer, but basically android is a somewhat atypical embedded linux, with a custom runtime environment (avoiding GPL userspace components) and a somewhat java-like virtual machine on top of that.

Typically the device manufacturer would supply at least the kernel drivers for the hardware, if they are marketing it as an android compatible platform.  There have been some problems with lesser manufacturers failing to provide kernel sources or possibly even sources of the version of GCC they are using, so choose hardware with care!